# How to append Newman htmlextra results to existing htmlextra report file

Tags: postman, newman

I have two *Newman* commands

1. `newman run collection.json -e env.json --folder create_clients -d clients.csv -r htmlextra --htmlreporter-export reporter.html`
2. `newman run collection.json -e env.json --folder create_orders -d orders.csv -r htmlextra --htmlreporter-export reporter.html`

After command #2 is executed reporter.html is overwritten, I want results to be appended.

Is there any possibility, please suggest, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reporter doesn't work in that way. You cannot append the results from a previous run as it creates a brand new report again.

Contextually, those are 2 different Collection runs. It would be the same if you were to run those in the app and see the results in the Runner.

If you wanted to see both reports individually, you would need to give them a different name, when exporting, or remove the `export` flag and the default filename would be created in the `/newman` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The `--htmlreporter-export reporter.html` parameter says to newman to save the html report in a file called `reporter.html`, so each time you run your command, this file is overwriten.

If you need to save your file with a different name, you can try to add a timestamp to it's name. On unix system, you can try something like :

```
--htmlreporter-export reporter-`date +'%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'`.html
```

This will append the output of the `date` command (formated in a Year-Month-Day-Hour-Min-Sec number string) in the file name, so if your commands runs more than one second, each result will be in a different file (you can of course add -%N to have nano seconds, or `man date` to seek other usefull values !).

But, you know, using standard outputs is a good practice : everybody using newman expect results to be found as `newman/newman-run-report-[date].[json|xml|html]`, so unless you have an uncommun need to get the result elsewhere, Keep It Simple, and don't reinvent the wheel :-)